# Trying to Install 3.8.12 Python and It Keeps Using 2.7

Tags: python, linux, pyenv

It seems no matter how I try to conquer PyEnv running with 3.8.12 it still wants to run with 2.7

[image]

I'm out of ideas on how to get this to accurately reflect the Python environment version of 3.8.12.

Comment: it should be available from `pyenv which python`

Comment: have you set the python version on the PATH environment variable?

Comment: export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy

fi
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

Comment: @NuMa this what I have for the path above. Maybe that's overkill and I need something less? This is what I have for my local bash and I can install fine - this is someone else's install I'm trying to get to work now :(

Comment: @9769953 brew install pyenv

Comment: @9769953 I'm storing the PATH variables above in .zprofile maybe I should move them to another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Homebrew, it is likely that `$PYENV_ROOT/bin` (i.e., `/Users/<account>/.pyenv/bin`) is empty, or even non-existent. That doesn't really matter, since the `pyenv` executable is probably on your path, e.g. somewhere in `/usr/local/bin`. Just in case, you can simply link it anyway:

```
mkdir -p $PYENV_ROOT/bin
cd $PYENV_ROOT/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pyenv
cd
```

But, that will likely not matter, nor solve your issue.

---

What you probably forget, is the line

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

in `$HOME/.zprofile`, as mentioned in the [GitHub README of the project](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) (search for "zprofile").
Just add the line, creating the file if necessary.

The line

```
eval "$(pyenv init --)"
```

should also be used, but in `$HOME/.zshrc`. I see this line in your comment, but apparently in `.zprofile` (inside an if-statement). Perhaps that will work, perhaps you need to move it to `.zshrc`.

Now restart the terminal (or just `source ~/.zprofile`, or even paste the line directly into the terminal for a one-off local session use), and you should be good to go.

---

Note that it looks like the `pyenv` initialisation has been simplified: no need for the if-statement anymore. For details, I refer again to the [GitHub README of the project](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick I can now activate a pyenv virtualenv with 3.8.12 and it is reflected as such. Running into a different issue now but I'll open a new question for that. Appreciate you!